Relative clauses in LFG
R Kaplan in "Handbook of LFG" uses a HEAD function that takes info from a higher f-structure (pred, number, gender, etc). Then it can share it with the relative pronoun or with nothing. This HEAD then uses the path to identify with some GF.
Q: Why is it positied if information-sharing can be done directly from the head noun? This account appears justified if there is a relative pronoun and a presumptive pronoun in a language.
